# How can I pass extras to an intent inside of a TabActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-tabhost, tabactivity

I have a TabActivity that hosts many tabs. Each tab refers to the same activity, however logic is performed inside the activity that determines what to load. I would like this to be done by passing a boolean to the respective tab. How can I do this?

```
package com.stocktwits.activity;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class StockTwitsTabActivity extends TabActivity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.stocktwits_tab_activity);

        Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, StreamActivity.class);

        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        intent.putExtra("reloadAll", true);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("all").setIndicator("All",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        // Do the same for the other tabs
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, StreamActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("home").setIndicator("Home",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, StreamActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("mentions").setIndicator("Mentions",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, StreamActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("directs").setIndicator("Directs",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, StreamActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("more").setIndicator("More",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using activity instead a view if the view is always the same for each tab? I think you could use `android.widget.TabHost.OnTabChangeListener` and handle here the content of the main view

Comment: can you provide me an example of a TabHost that loads views instead of activities?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're doing it wrong. Why would you want the same activity passed to all the tabs? Either use different activities, or different views. Not the same activity.

Comment: My activity is populating a listview from some url's. There are probably 10 different urls which I'm toggling between. Does that sound right? Or do I still need to be using different views? It would be bad practice to create 10 different activities.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135023/is-it-possible-to-define-each-tabs-content-in-a-separate-xml-file/3136218#3136218)

Let me know if this is a valid solution for your purpose